# Text fadein/fadeout animation in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create simple animation in loop but every time it works wrong.

How should it work?

> **Test 1** fadein, wait 2 seconds and
>
> **Test 2** fadein, wait 2 seconds and
>
> **Test 3** fadein, wait 2 seconds and
>
> **Test 4** fadein, wait 2 seconds and
>
> fadeout **Test 1, Test 2, Test 3, Test 4** at the same time (important, I can't achieve this)
>
> then
>
> **Test 5** fadein, wait 2 seconds and
>
> **Test 6** fadein, wait 2 seconds and
>
> **Test 7** fadein, wait 2 seconds and
>
> **Test 8** fadein, wait 2 seconds and
>
> fadeout **Test 5, Test 6, Test 7, Test 8** at the same time (important, I can't achieve this)
>
> loop all process.

My html code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 slogan text-right">
    <h1 class="slogan1">test 1</h1>
    <h1 class="slogan2">test 2</h1>
    <h1 class="slogan3">test 3</h1>
    <p  class="slogan4">test 4</p>

    <h1 class="slogan5">test 5</h1>
    <h1 class="slogan6">test 6</h1>
    <h1 class="slogan7">test 7</h1>
    <p class="slogan8">test 8</p>
</div>
```

And here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var cycle;

        (cycle = function() {
            $('.slogan1').delay(1000).fadeIn(3000);
            $('.slogan2').delay(3000).fadeIn(3000);
            $('.slogan3').delay(5000).fadeIn(3000);
            $('.slogan4').delay(7000).fadeIn(3000);
            $('.slogan1, .slogan2, .slogan3, .slogan4').delay(10000).fadeOut(3000);

            $('.slogan5').delay(13000).fadeIn(3000);
            $('.slogan6').delay(15000).fadeIn(3000);
            $('.slogan7').delay(17000).fadeIn(3000);
            $('.slogan8').delay(19000).fadeIn(3000);
            $('.slogan5, .slogan6, .slogan7, .slogan8').delay(21000).fadeOut(3000);

        })();
    });
```

Comment: and your js looks like .. (share!) ?

Comment: My JS is I guess completely wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a different approach, which kind of works like a plugin, with options:

```
/* The cycle function performs successive fadeIns using the provided selectors
 * and finishes by fading them all out, and executing a provided callback
 */
function cycle(options) {
  var settings = {
    'selectors': options.selectors || [],
    'remaining': options.selectors.slice().reverse() || [],
    'delay'    : options.delay || 1000,
    'duration' : options.duration || 3000,
    'complete' : options.complete || function() {}
  };

  cycleStep();

  function cycleStep() {
    if(!settings.remaining.length){
        var callbackExecuted = false;
        $( settings.selectors.join(', ') ).delay(settings.delay)
                                          .fadeOut(settings.duration, function(){
                                            if(!callbackExecuted){
                                                settings.complete();
                                                callbackExecuted = true;
                                              }
                                          });
    }
    else
        $( settings.remaining.pop() ).delay(settings.delay)
                                     .fadeIn(settings.duration, cycleStep);
  }
}

/* This function will loop the cycles with the options you provide it */
function myLoop(){
  cycle({
    selectors: ['.slogan1', '.slogan2', '.slogan3', '.slogan4'],
    complete: function() {
      cycle({
        selectors: ['.slogan5', '.slogan6', '.slogan7', '.slogan8'],
        complete: myLoop
      });
    }
  });
}

// Execute the loop
myLoop();
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: Works just perfect without any modifications. Thank you.

Comment: Haha, a tiiiny little bit overdone, but you have my upvote.

Comment: I can't blieve this all that for looping ?? what about `setInterval`.

Comment: @Shomz Haha, I totally agree, but I try as much as I can to make reusable code (thank you!). @Zakaria , yes, that's a lot of code for this functionality, but for the same reason. Also, as Shomz mentioned it in his answer, using  successive delays or `setInterval`s is inaccurate and may result in interesting behaviors if it runs for a long time (overlapping fadeIns).

Comment: I see @WalterWhite but Take a look at my updated answer using just `setInterval`.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0x5xssk/24/)**

Using `setInterval` for loop :

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('.test1, .test2').show();
    $(".test1 [class*='slogan'], .test2 [class*='slogan']").hide();

    cycle();
}, 6000);
```

Try to group the first 4 test under div with class `test1`, and same for second tests with class `test2` :

**JS :**

```
cycle = function() {
    $('.slogan1').delay(500).fadeIn();
    $('.slogan2').delay(1000).fadeIn();
    $('.slogan3').delay(1500).fadeIn();
    $('.slogan4').delay(2000).fadeIn();
    $('.test1').delay(2500).fadeOut();

    $('.slogan5').delay(3000).fadeIn();
    $('.slogan6').delay(3500).fadeIn();
    $('.slogan7').delay(4000).fadeIn();
    $('.slogan8').delay(4500).fadeIn();
    $('.test2').delay(5000).fadeOut();
};

cycle();
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="col-md-12 slogan text-right">
    <div class="test1">
        <h1 class="slogan1">test 1</h1>
        <h1 class="slogan2">test 2</h1>
        <h1 class="slogan3">test 3</h1>
        <p  class="slogan4">test 4</p>
    </div>

    <div class="test2">
        <h1 class="slogan5">test 5</h1>
        <h1 class="slogan6">test 6</h1>
        <h1 class="slogan7">test 7</h1>
        <p  class="slogan8">test 8</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: But how to loop this animation ?

Comment: @Shomz How you find this solution ? :)

Comment: I don't like the use of delays (as you probably guessed), and a lot of manual work makes the whole code a hell to maintain (imagine adding a few elements or switching places of elements). :)

Comment: Ok @Shomz thanks for your answer, just knowing that the other answer also use delay and use static selectors (what means everytime adding an element we have to add it to the code...) anyway thanks and have a great day.

Answer (score 2):

Using delays is innacurate and your animations will start overlapping in time. I suggest you us callback functions, like this:

```js
var i = 0,
    delay = 2000;

function show(){
  if (i && i % 4 == 0 && $('.slogan > *:visible').length > 0) {
    $('.slogan > *:visible').fadeOut().promise().done(doShow);
    if (i == 8)
      i = 0;
  }
  else 
    doShow();  
}

function doShow(){
  $('.slogan > *').eq(i++).fadeIn(function(){
    setTimeout(show, delay);
  })
}

show();
```

```css
.slogan > * {display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 slogan text-right">
    <h1 class="slogan1">test 1</h1>
    <h1 class="slogan2">test 2</h1>
    <h1 class="slogan3">test 3</h1>
    <p  class="slogan4">test 4</p>

    <h1 class="slogan5">test 5</h1>
    <h1 class="slogan6">test 6</h1>
    <h1 class="slogan7">test 7</h1>
    <p class="slogan8">test 8</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You also have my vote, as your code is straight forward and answers OP's question. I have overdone it to make it more reusable.

Answer (score 1):

it's more efficient to put a class around the two sections and fadeout those.
I don't think this works straight away but, gets you in the right way

```
<div class="col-md-12 slogan text-right">
    <div class='section1'>
        <h1 class="slogan1">test 1</h1>
        <h1 class="slogan2">test 2</h1>
        <h1 class="slogan3">test 3</h1>
        <p  class="slogan4">test 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class='section2'>
        <h1 class="slogan5">test 5</h1>
        <h1 class="slogan6">test 6</h1>
        <h1 class="slogan7">test 7</h1>
        <p class="slogan8">test 8</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and js

```
var counter = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    counter++

    $('.slogan'+counter).delay(1000).fadeIn(3000);

    if (counter === 4) $('section1').delay(1000).fadeOut(3000);
    if(counter > 8){ 
        $('section2').delay(1000).fadeOut(3000);
         counter = 0
       }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: I know but I have to do this in this way. I mean animate elements one by one.

Comment: but when you use   $('.slogan5, .slogan6, .slogan7, .slogan8').delay(21000).fadeOut(3000);

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var itemIndex = 0;
function changeDisp(){
    if(itemIndex > 0 && itemIndex % 4 == 0){
        $('.slogan').children().slice(0, itemIndex ).hide('slow');
        if(itemIndex == 8)
            itemIndex = 0;
    }
    $('.slogan').children().eq(itemIndex).fadeIn();
    itemIndex++;
}
setInterval(changeDisp, 2000);
```

```css
.slogan h1, .slogan p{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 slogan text-right">
    <h1 class="slogan1">test 1</h1>
    <h1 class="slogan2">test 2</h1>
    <h1 class="slogan3">test 3</h1>
    <p  class="slogan4">test 4</p>

    <h1 class="slogan5">test 5</h1>
    <h1 class="slogan6">test 6</h1>
    <h1 class="slogan7">test 7</h1>
    <p class="slogan8">test 8</p>
</div>
```